Open print dialog on page load in Angular 17
Having this script tag in any HTML page would have open the print dialog box on page load but in Angular 17, this do not get rendered.
<script>window.onload = function(){ window.print(); };</script>
<div>This is a print page</div>

I tried adding this JS code too in the .ts file but it throws and error:
export class PrintComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    onload='window.print()';
  }
}

ERROR:
print.component.ts:13:5 - error TS2322: Type '"window.print()"' is not assignable to type '((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null'.

13     onload='window.print()';

How do I call window.print on page load in an Angular 17 project? I have searched far and wide without any solution.

if you have ssr enabled project:
constructor() {
afterNextRender(() => {
  window.print();
})

}
if you have browser only project:
ngOnInit(): void {
  window.print();
}


Got it working with your second method. So simple and so elegant. Thank You.
